# Maven pmd plugin - Exclude/Disable a rule

Tags: maven, maven-3, pmd

I'm attempting to exclude a certain rule from pmd using the maven-pmd-plugin (in a multi-module maven project).

**Approach:**

Using the excludeFromFailureFile
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/violation-exclusions.html

Ideally, I want to exclude this rule for the entire product (based on a parent package), however,to being with I tested for a particular class - even that is not working.

**Environment**

Java 7, Maven 3.0.3

```
<plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.1</version>
       <executions>
         <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <excludeFromFailureFile>exclude-pmd.properties</excludeFromFailureFile>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
             <goals>
                 <goal>cpd-check</goal>
             </goals>
          <!-- Added explicit execution Id to avoid the below problem -->
      <!-- 'build.pluginManagement.plugins.plugin[org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin].executions.execution.id' must be unique but found duplicate execution with id default @ line 1423, column 36 -->
            <id>cpd-check</id>
          </execution>
   </executions>
```

Contents of exclude-pmd.properties

```
mycompany.project.classA=UselessParentheses
```

Comment: This seems to be a bug in maven-pmd-plugin, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MPMD-243

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to exclude rules, is providing your own ruleset file. You can see where to find the default ruleset file in the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726383/pmd-ruleset-file) question. If you are using Sonar, you can retrieve the file using the permalink.
Copy the file to your parent module, and then you can customize it, deleting the rules you want to exclude, and use the following configuration:
in the **parent** `pom.xml`:

```
...
<properties>
    <main.basedir>${project.basedir}</main.basedir> 
    <!-- Some child module could set this to true to skip PMD check -->
    <skip.pmd.check>false</skip.pmd.check>
</properties>
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
    <!-- This is the version I'm using -->
    <version>2.7.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <rulesets>
            <ruleset>${main.basedir}/path/to/pmd-rules.xml</ruleset>
        </rulesets>
        <skip>${skip.pmd.check}</skip>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>pmd-config</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

in child **modules** `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
    <main.basedir>${project.parent.basedir}</main.basedir>
</properties>
```

in some **module** you want to skip (i.e contains generated code):

```
<properties>
    <main.basedir>${project.parent.basedir}</main.basedir>
    <skip.pmd.check>true</skip.pmd.check>
</properties>
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Appreciate your detailed answer with helpful comments, Thanks! Is there a chance that new rules could be added to the default pmd set? In which case I would have to start comparing and maintaining the custom pmd file? Also, i'm thinking it would be intuitive for the pmd community to support exclude rules.

Comment: You can, in fact, exclude rules from a ruleset ref. Take a look into "Excluding rules from a ruleset" section [here](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.0/howtomakearuleset.html). So, instead of deleting the rules from the "default" file, you can create another rulset, ref the default file, and exclude the rules. About worrying for the custom pmd file, I think your only worry is some for  some major change in PMD that breaks compatibility with the rulset file syntax.