# Pmd. how to configure ruleset?

Tags: java, maven, pmd

I have following pmd configuration in my pom.xml

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.3</version>
      <configuration>
        <includeTests>true</includeTests>
        <printFailingErrors>true</printFailingErrors>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <rulesets>
          <ruleset>rulesets/java/basic.xml</ruleset>
          <ruleset>rulesets/java/braces.xml</ruleset>
          <!--<ruleset>rulesets/java/junit.xml</ruleset>-->
          <ruleset>rulesets/java/unusedcode.xml</ruleset>
          <!--<ruleset>rulesets/java/codesize.xml</ruleset>-->
          <ruleset>ruleset-naming.xml</ruleset>
          <ruleset>rulesets/java/imports.xml</ruleset>
          <ruleset>rulesets/java/empty.xml</ruleset>
          <ruleset>rulesets/jsp/basic.xml</ruleset>
        </rulesets>
        <includes>
          <include>**\/*.jsp</include>
          <include>**\/*.java</include>
        </includes>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>check</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <excludeFromFailureFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/exclude-pmd.properties</excludeFromFailureFile>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

If I uncomment

```
    <ruleset>rulesets/java/junit.xml</ruleset>
```

PMD complains:

```
    JUnit assertions should include a message.
    UnitTestContainsTooManyAsserts Priority:3 JUnit tests should not contain more than 1 assert(s)
    JUnitAssertionsShouldIncludeMessage Priority:3 JUnit assertions should include a message.
```

I don't want to follow these rules. I want to disable them. I could not find these files in my project.

Where can I show rule set?
How can I disable concrete rule?

### P.S.

It is content of **ruleset-naming.xml**

```
    <ruleset name="Maven Ruleset"
             xmlns="http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset/1.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset/1.0.0 http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset_xml_schema.xsd"
             xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset_xml_schema.xsd">
    
    
        <rule ref="rulesets/java/naming.xml">
            <exclude name="ShortVariable"/>
            <exclude name="LongVariable"/>
            <exclude name="ShortClassName"/>
        </rule>
        <rule ref="rulesets/java/junit.xml">
            <exclude name="JUnitAssertionsShouldIncludeMessage"/>
        </rule>
    </ruleset>
```

but I run build and anyway see message:

```
[INFO] PMD Failure: com.terminal.service.impl.ContentServiceImplTest:111 Rule:JUnitAssertionsShouldIncludeMessage Priority:3 JUnit assertions should include a message.
```

### Solution:

1. remove `<ruleset>rulesets/java/junit.xml</ruleset>` from pom.xml
2. added inside `ruleset-naming.xml`

```
 <ruleset name="Maven Ruleset"
          xmlns="http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset/1.0.0 http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset_xml_schema.xsd"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset_xml_schema.xsd">
 
     <rule ref="rulesets/java/junit.xml">
         <exclude name="JUnitAssertionsShouldIncludeMessage"/>
         <exclude name="JUnitTestContainsTooManyAsserts"/>
         <exclude name="JUnitTestsShouldIncludeAssert"/>
     </rule>
 
 </ruleset>
```

picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to exclude PMD checks per class and per rule. This is configured with the [`excludeFromFailureFile`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/check-mojo.html#excludeFromFailureFile) attribute of the `maven-pmd-plugin`. This attribute must point a properties file that lists the excludes.

[Sample file](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/violation-exclusions.html):

```
org.apache.maven.ClassA=UnitTestContainsTooManyAsserts,JUnitAssertionsShouldIncludeMessage
org.apache.maven.ClassB=UnitTestContainsTooManyAsserts,JUnitAssertionsShouldIncludeMessage
```

If you have a lot of classes and want to disable those checks for every class, another option is to copy the file `rulesets/java/junit.xml` and make your own rule set by deleting the rules you do not want to check ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22717676/1743880)).

Comment: Should I modify **exclude-pmd.properties** ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow Yes, it should be like the sample I gave in my answer.

Comment: looks that I did all according your advise but it doesn't work(

Comment: I didn't catch where should I copy **rulesets/java/junit.xml**.  from **.m2** foder ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow You can copy the modified `junit.xml` inside `src/main/resources` for example. Then reference it in the `<ruleset>` configuration of your plugin, like `<ruleset>src/main/resources/modified-junit.xml</ruleset>`

Comment: I have a bit miunderstanding. As I understoo 2 option.

Comment: 1 - copy junit.xml to my source, point to this file from pom.xm and moufy content of this file

Comment: 2 - add excluion rules to **ruleset-naming.xml**

Comment: your first advise lead to replace failures with warning